# Poetry error on install - SecretStorage required

Tags: python, python-poetry

I'm trying to execute `poetry install`, but I got errors

```
Cannot install pyasn1.
  RuntimeError
  SecretStorage required
```

And when I try to poetry add SecretStorage, I got the same `SecretStorage required`

What should I do to fix that?

(Python version - 3.11, operating system - Macos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is based on source: https://github.com/orgs/python-poetry/discussions/7119#discussioncomment-4394623

> It wasn't necessarily `SecretStorage` causing the received error, it was
> that `python-keychain` was looking for `SecretStorage` to be
> configured and implemented, when it was not. A few weeks ago, I
> attempted to implement `secretservice` for another application, but
> abandoned the implementation. I knew there was a modified
> configuration file somewhere on my system that was configured to use
> the now defunct `secretservice` implementation, but since I never
> received any sign specifically pointing to this misconfigured file, I
> assumed it wasn't a concern. When all along, poetry was pointing right
> at the issue, in it's own way.
>
> `~/.config/python-keyring/keyringer.cfg` was the file in question that
> was modified to use the defunct `secretservice` implementation. I
> simply exchanged
> `default-keyring=keyring.backends.secretservice.Keyring` for
> `default-keyring=keyring.backends.null.Keyring`. Immediately after
> which, poetry ceased output of the error, and is back to working
> fantastically.